# Is there a way to create hyperlink within Vue argument

Tags: html, vue.js

I have a function that creates a text box that alters within each `name`. The thing is, I want *one* of these description arguments to allow a hyperlink within the text.
example:

```
var maps = new Vue({
   el: "#maps",
   data: {
      selected: 'US County'
      maps = [
       { 
           name: 'US County'
           description: "This is where I want my **hyperlink** to go"
       }
      ]
   }
 })
```

I want the hyperlink to be within this description argument among separate text..I tried using `<a href...` but it wasn't working.

I am relatively new to HTML and Vue JS so I apologize if this question does not entirely make sense.

Answer (score 0):

If using Vue 2, check out [this page](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Raw-HTML), which shows how to bind a variable and display it as HTML. You will also want to be sure to store your description + HTML as a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Template should be something similar to:

```
<template>
  <div v-html="maps[0].description"></div>
</template>
```

Notice the backticks in the description. This is called a template literal. Your script should be similar to the following:

```
   var maps = new Vue({
   el: "#maps",
   data: {
      selected: 'US County'
      maps = [
       { 
           name: 'US County'
           description: `This is where I want my <a href="blahblah">link</a> to go`
       }
      ]
   }
 })
```

Comment: `<a v-bind:href="https://www.blahblah.com"> click here </a> `within  the `description` argument, but it still is not generatiung a hyperlink, the entire thing is returning as a text string.

Comment: Updated my answer to further clarify.

Comment: If this helped, please mark as an answer.

Comment: I did this and I was able to get the hyperlink to show, but its not within the selected "map". Its creating the hyperlink within each #maps argument, of which there are 4. I want only one of them to show(within the text description it is still makred as an entire text string, even with using the template literal

Comment: When creating the hyperlink, you need to see if the map.name is equal to selected. If it is, then display the hyperlink. Without your code, nobody can be of much more help, but take a look at https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html for help on conditional rendering, which is what you need.